# Subsonic and sp_help_job

Tags: subsonic

Is it possible for subsonic to access dbo.sp_help_job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SubSonic is an ORM tool that also wraps SP's but does not generate code for system SP's and the project is open source so you can edit the code to your need